# Pandas - concat two df along non-index axis, merge rows that have same value on non-index axis

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes that I want to combine into one. I want the resulting dataframe to be sorted along a non-index axis, `'seconds_since_start'` in my case. I want to merge rows that have the same value for `'seconds_since_start'`. I also want to retain the unique columns between the two dataframes.

Showing the given input and desired output is probably easier.

---

```
df_a = """
valid_a,value_a,seconds_since_start
2000-02-15 14:47:00,12.3,0.0
2000-02-15 15:59:00,20.6,30.0
2000-02-15 16:51:00,20.3,120.0
2000-02-15 17:52:00,22.6,200.0
"""

df_b = """
valid_b,value_b,seconds_since_start
2019-12-24 14:54:00,12.4,20.0
2019-12-24 15:54:00,18.7,30.0
2019-12-24 16:54:00,19.2,90.0
2019-12-24 17:54:00,20.8,250.0
"""

df_desired_output = """
valid_a,valid_b,value_a,value_b,seconds_since_start
2000-02-15 14:47:00,,12.3,,0.0
,2019-12-24 14:54:00,,12.4,20.0
2000-02-15 15:59:00,2019-12-24 15:54:00,20.6,18.7,30.0
,2019-12-24 16:54:00,,19.2,90.0
2000-02-15 16:51:00,,20.3,,120.0
2000-02-15 17:52:00,,22.6,,200.0
,2019-12-24 17:54:00,,20.8,250.0
"""

from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_a = StringIO(df_a)
df_a = pd.read_csv(df_a)
df_a['valid_a'] = pd.to_datetime(df_a['valid_a'])  # convert 'valid' column to pd.datetime objects
df_a = df_a.set_index('valid_a')  # set the 'valid' as index

df_b = StringIO(df_b)
df_b = pd.read_csv(df_b)
df_b['valid_b'] = pd.to_datetime(df_b['valid_b'])  # convert 'valid' column to pd.datetime objects
df_b = df_b.set_index('valid_b')  # set the 'valid' as index

df_desired_output = StringIO(df_desired_output)
df_desired_output = pd.read_csv(df_desired_output)


print('input dataframe A\n', df_a)
print('input dataframe B\n', df_b)
print('desired output dataframe\n', df_desired_output)

df_new = pd.concat([df_a, df_b], sort=False)  # can't sort by 'seconds_since_start' from here so I do it on the next line
df_new = df_new.sort_values(by='seconds_since_start')  # sort
print('actual output\n', df_new)  # fails to merge rows that have the same value for 'seconds_since_start'
```

---

**Output**

```
input dataframe A
                      value_a  seconds_since_start
valid_a                                          
2000-02-15 14:47:00     12.3                  0.0
2000-02-15 15:59:00     20.6                 30.0
2000-02-15 16:51:00     20.3                120.0
2000-02-15 17:52:00     22.6                200.0
input dataframe B
                      value_b  seconds_since_start
valid_b                                          
2019-12-24 14:54:00     12.4                 20.0
2019-12-24 15:54:00     18.7                 30.0
2019-12-24 16:54:00     19.2                 90.0
2019-12-24 17:54:00     20.8                250.0
desired output dataframe
                valid_a              valid_b  ...  value_b  seconds_since_start
0  2000-02-15 14:47:00                  NaN  ...      NaN                  0.0
1                  NaN  2019-12-24 14:54:00  ...     12.4                 20.0
2  2000-02-15 15:59:00  2019-12-24 15:54:00  ...     18.7                 30.0
3                  NaN  2019-12-24 16:54:00  ...     19.2                 90.0
4  2000-02-15 16:51:00                  NaN  ...      NaN                120.0
5  2000-02-15 17:52:00                  NaN  ...      NaN                200.0
6                  NaN  2019-12-24 17:54:00  ...     20.8                250.0

[7 rows x 5 columns]
actual output
                      value_a  seconds_since_start  value_b
2000-02-15 14:47:00     12.3                  0.0      NaN
2019-12-24 14:54:00      NaN                 20.0     12.4
2000-02-15 15:59:00     20.6                 30.0      NaN
2019-12-24 15:54:00      NaN                 30.0     18.7
2019-12-24 16:54:00      NaN                 90.0     19.2
2000-02-15 16:51:00     20.3                120.0      NaN
2000-02-15 17:52:00     22.6                200.0      NaN
2019-12-24 17:54:00      NaN                250.0     20.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just merge:

```
pd.merge(df_a.reset_index(), 
         df_b.reset_index(), 
         on='seconds_since_start', 
         how='outer')
```

Output:

```
    valid_a                value_a    seconds_since_start  valid_b                value_b
--  -------------------  ---------  ---------------------  -------------------  ---------
 0  2000-02-15 14:47:00       12.3                      0  NaT                      nan
 1  2000-02-15 15:59:00       20.6                     30  2019-12-24 15:54:00       18.7
 2  2000-02-15 16:51:00       20.3                    120  NaT                      nan
 3  2000-02-15 17:52:00       22.6                    200  NaT                      nan
 4  NaT                      nan                       20  2019-12-24 14:54:00       12.4
 5  NaT                      nan                       90  2019-12-24 16:54:00       19.2
 6  NaT                      nan                      250  2019-12-24 17:54:00       20.8
```

Comment: `reset_index` creates a copy by default, so your original dataframes are intact.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the index to columns

```
df_new = pd.concat([df_a.assign(valid_a=df_a.index), df_b.assign(valid_b=df_b.index)], sort=False)  
df_new = df_new.sort_values(by='seconds_since_start')
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example using merge. First reset the indices in df_a and df_b then perform an outer join and sort values:

```
df_a.reset_index().merge(df_b.reset_index(),
                         on=['seconds_since_start'],
                         how='outer').sort_values('seconds_since_start')

              valid_a  value_a  seconds_since_start             valid_b  \
0 2000-02-15 14:47:00     12.3                  0.0                 NaT   
4                 NaT      NaN                 20.0 2019-12-24 14:54:00   
1 2000-02-15 15:59:00     20.6                 30.0 2019-12-24 15:54:00   
5                 NaT      NaN                 90.0 2019-12-24 16:54:00   
2 2000-02-15 16:51:00     20.3                120.0                 NaT   
3 2000-02-15 17:52:00     22.6                200.0                 NaT   
6                 NaT      NaN                250.0 2019-12-24 17:54:00   

   value_b  
0      NaN  
4     12.4  
1     18.7  
5     19.2  
2      NaN  
3      NaN  
6     20.8
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `seconds_since_start` is unique within `df_a` and `df_b`:

```
col = 'seconds_since_start'

s = pd.concat([df_a[col], df_b[col]]).sort_values().to_frame()
output = s.merge(df_a, on=col, how='left') \
          .merge(df_b, on=col, how='left')
```

Result:

```
   seconds_since_start              valid_a  value_a              valid_b  value_b
0                  0.0  2000-02-15 14:47:00     12.3                  NaN      NaN
1                 20.0                  NaN      NaN  2019-12-24 14:54:00     12.4
2                 30.0  2000-02-15 15:59:00     20.6  2019-12-24 15:54:00     18.7
3                 30.0  2000-02-15 15:59:00     20.6  2019-12-24 15:54:00     18.7
4                 90.0                  NaN      NaN  2019-12-24 16:54:00     19.2
5                120.0  2000-02-15 16:51:00     20.3                  NaN      NaN
6                200.0  2000-02-15 17:52:00     22.6                  NaN      NaN
7                250.0                  NaN      NaN  2019-12-24 17:54:00     20.8
```

Comment: In the resulting df every row must have a unique value for `seconds_since_start` You have to rows with `30.0`